# passing the variable

Tags: php, html

I am newbie of PHP. I had a website which someone code it before. He used the htacess to exchange all of the link from dot php to dot html of website. Now i continue to write a new function.

In this new function have to create one  tags display a contact number, after user click on the  it will link to contact detail page and pass the contact number to the detail page also to query the suitable contact detail

Now is the problem : IF i write

```
<a href=/B2C/vi/Contact_detail.html?id_contact=$contact_number>$contact_number</a>
```

I can't $_GET id_contact because the link in href is Dot HTML instead of PHP
(this link has been define in htacess and i have to follow this structre)

If i change the href link to

```
<a href=/blocks/vi/Contact_detail.php?id_contact=$contact_number>$contact_number</a>
```

The page could not found because of the htaccess file. If i remove htacess file, i have to repair all of the link inside of website. It's impossible

My question is how can i use the html link but also can pass and GET the variable from address bar after ? 
Does anyone can give me a suggestion. Thanks for your help

Here is my code

```
    <?php
    while ($row = db2_fetch_both($stmt))
    {
        $po_holder_name = $row['POL_HOLDER_NM'];
        $insured_name = $row['INSURED_NM'];
        $main_po_num = $row['POL_NUM'];
        $pro_name = $row['PRO_NAME'];
        $po_valid = $row['POL_VALID_NAME'];
        $staff_num = $row['EMP_NO'];
        $service_cen = $row['DIV_NAME'];
        $staff_cel = $row['MOBILE_PHONE'];

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$po_holder_name</td>";
        echo "<td>$insured_name</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=/B2C/$lang/Contact_detail.html>$main_po_num</a></td>";
        echo "<td>$pro_name</td>";
        echo "<td>$po_valid</td>";
        echo "<td>$staff_num</td>";
        echo "<td>$service_cen</td>";
        echo "<td>$staff_cel</td>";
        echo "</tr>";   

    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

you can see contact number is an array and very difficult to save in a SESSION variable

Comment: Can you post the content of the htaccess file ?

Answer (score 0):

So you can use .phtml extention

http://filext.com/file-extension/PHTML

i'm using it on all my view on Zend Framework

Answer (score 0):

If the script runs, but the $_GET value is empty, it might be that the rewrite rule in your .htaccess is discarding the query string.

This needs fixing in the .htaccess file. Find a line that looks something like:

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.html $1.php?
```

and simply delete the question mark after php:

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.html $1.php
```

If there isn't a question mark there then you may have a different problem.

Comment: I found it already. No question mark like what you said. Thanks for your helping. Will remember it and may use in furture

Answer (score -2):

Add this line to your .htaccess file to make your html files execute php code:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Reference :
http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the positive advice !

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried to at 

AddType application/x-httpd-php .html to my htaccess but still cannot work . Here is some image 

Please help me to download the image from mediafire hosting. I am so sorry about this inconvenience because i don't have enough reputation to post image here. Sorry again and thanks in advance

http://www.mediafire.com/?t9fsx01ia9s0hcu

Comment: Hmmmm, then i think the problem is in the htaccess ...
You can try out to remove the htaccess and fix the links, what you should try to do is to use "replace all" in your editor and replace all .html to .php (as an example), i know it isn't that easy/quick ...
(don't forget to make a backup before you do these manipulations ...)

Comment: Oh my god! i think this is the best way and the only way i can do. Thanks for your information. Let's me do it with a cup of coffee.